# RSA encryption in C# is different from other language

Tags: javascript, python, c#, rsa

I am trying to encrypting data in C#

In other language, every encrypted data ended in "==" but in C#, they don't

why this happen?

**in python**

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_pksc1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

def encrpt(password, public_key):
    rsakey = RSA.importKey(public_key)
    cipher = Cipher_pksc1_v1_5.new(rsakey)
    cipher_text = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(password.encode("utf-8")))
    return cipher_text.decode()

public_key = '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA81dCnCKt0NVH7j5Oh2+S
GgEU0aqi5u6sYXemouJWXOlZO3jqDsHYM1qfEjVvCOmeoMNFXYSXdNhflU7mjWP8
jWUmkYIQ8o3FGqMzsMTNxr+bAp0cULWu9eYmycjJwWIxxB7vUwvpEUNicgW7v5nC
wmF5HS33Hmn7yDzcfjfBs99K5xJEppHG0qc+q3YXxxPpwZNIRFn0Wtxt0Muh1U8a
vvWyw03uQ/wMBnzhwUC8T4G5NclLEWzOQExbQ4oDlZBv8BM/WxxuOyu0I8bDUDdu
tJOfREYRZBlazFHvRKNNQQD2qDfjRz484uFs7b5nykjaMB9k/EJAuHjJzGs9MMMW
tQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
'''

print(encrpt("abc", public_key))
```

**result**

```
jA14duvhdPVipkWYJrvRXuNpD6yNXRwb/VnyEmc8G1UFxQoxhm8j0nPNZFuQ48oB8jZmd0kGBfwwQluPtYrJCqbtZ9qamnNp+xtSHE5BUsbXtfuF55ppWGmPsQkEUADNodMidHeUgGuP4g3E25/Vumx6iN0vRNZNFw3WFOPwAZVQEmNGfN3J2Xa3BSuaVyDh4mLp/SD5wK6ffv5+aSXP3HZQPWVe/YW3+Ok6+O3adVJ4T6r2NNIwabR+aQDqH2rCAePIum8qm8ZcV93jX0y+8pvfHzaSMzNH1dpTjPR47rUatlx44jG2ORKnvfRkACcCS+HhHfQ87WCYxCVUhWuflQ==
```

**in JavaScript**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsencrypt/2.3.1/jsencrypt.min.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    const crypt = new JSEncrypt();
    crypt.setPublicKey("MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA81dCnCKt0NVH7j5Oh2+SGgEU0aqi5u6sYXemouJWXOlZO3jqDsHYM1qfEjVvCOmeoMNFXYSXdNhflU7mjWP8jWUmkYIQ8o3FGqMzsMTNxr+bAp0cULWu9eYmycjJwWIxxB7vUwvpEUNicgW7v5nCwmF5HS33Hmn7yDzcfjfBs99K5xJEppHG0qc+q3YXxxPpwZNIRFn0Wtxt0Muh1U8avvWyw03uQ/wMBnzhwUC8T4G5NclLEWzOQExbQ4oDlZBv8BM/WxxuOyu0I8bDUDdutJOfREYRZBlazFHvRKNNQQD2qDfjRz484uFs7b5nykjaMB9k/EJAuHjJzGs9MMMWtQIDAQAB");
    const encrypted = crypt.encrypt("abc").trim();

    document.write(encrypted);
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

**result**

```
a6zdvw+y8wfQUns1UbwWPXBuChZK9mDx6x8fuX+AFcZC/HwOhU9YIl4vnSlrU5l4Kh7IUMP4LOx5o3Y4n39vXxj4oAEE1ab35y2elp1bYjQUZfXgULRAcx3O2iBSP7Dqht43HKPImagtE/aopuOuK6mwl2a1aeR7J0FCEpF2TXM2Xc+4obq0xXw+fapiGv1qGher0RbyKFNALnUeAfRtfWpYjTJ2XUlWRyE5jU455xmMl5QYFNiJa9R7GynZbolNEf9FIHBrMyuMXNB1OOAyPc6jbeSb2/IckoNR4YNS3IdQY+SE++cm9AvEqfI6e/wCWfJ2pkDN0x3kn+FDb0la5w==
```

**in C#**

```
public static void Main()
        {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider cipher = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            cipher.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA81dCnCKt0NVH7j5Oh2+SGgEU0aqi5u6sYXemouJWXOlZO3jqDsHYM1qfEjVvCOmeoMNFXYSXdNhflU7mjWP8jWUmkYIQ8o3FGqMzsMTNxr+bAp0cULWu9eYmycjJwWIxxB7vUwvpEUNicgW7v5nCwmF5HS33Hmn7yDzcfjfBs99K5xJEppHG0qc+q3YXxxPpwZNIRFn0Wtxt0Muh1U8avvWyw03uQ/wMBnzhwUC8T4G5NclLEWzOQExbQ4oDlZBv8BM/WxxuOyu0I8bDUDdutJOfREYRZBlazFHvRKNNQQD2qDfjRz484uFs7b5nykjaMB9k/EJAuHjJzGs9MMMWtQIDAQAB</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>");
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abc");
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.Encrypt(data, true);
            var result = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

**result**

```
IK47Ed8Yw8uAECMFgTMX7Ij7rAqj149QyO2AJ9P4YMzqu2MSAmRcSCKWaPzF9k8OXQmV/aXACjwJMBq2ikZjfBwuoax1rdiIdXFmvUSIbrTDAx83feTDRF+1wO31MROSXi99+LErMMMRPXacqYqcB1fy7b/NhbEdmNLHWCV62B1BvO+DCoDXHM+3ImkhbCTGU2Jeq1EkfCbJSL42RryJv6sKefmwjAcyEdXl/mSHUVdgOJrSbsCsNbkvy/iKq6ZcQnoSkxmlmF/VfFu0Ivj+31fcjY0OGkzD9CkCZGmxsRF1kG0F+lNbwbRPEU5q8pXPqCcas55BMKHJGt2EuK/662qqGr6iiSv1+YxOQ1aofV7dfoNe3sOTekpj3cVM5ART4uwOKNee
```

only in c# does not have "==" in end.
I tried many times and every cases were like this

I think I have big misunderstanding about rsa encrytion but I don't know what I misunderstand.
plz help me

Comment: In the C# code you use the PEM key as modulus. This is wrong, of course. Either determine the modulus from the PEM key or convert the PEM key online, e.g. with https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter. Depending on your C# version you can also import the key directly. Whether padding (=) is set for Base64 depends on the length of the data. With the right key the C# code will produce a ciphertext of the same length as the other codes with the same padding.

Comment: Note that the Python and JavaScript code use PKCS#1 v1.5 as padding, while the C# code applies OAEP. To use PKCS#1 v1.5 as well, set the 2nd parameter in `Encrypt()` to false.

Comment: @user9014097 I must have mentioned it before, but please just post that first comment as answer instead, it would obviously solve the problem. Then the answer gets accepted and we don't need to spend time on it.

Answer (score 0):

The ciphertext of all three codes is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded. Base64 uses a padding (`=`). Whether or not padding is applied depends on the length of the data. The C# code generates an incorrect ciphertext due to a bug in the key import (see below). As a result, the ciphertext has a different length than the ciphertexts of the other two codes, which is the reason for the different padding.

---

In the Python and JavaScript code, the public key is imported as PEM encoded X.509/SPKI key. In the C# code, it is imported as XML, using the body of the PEM encoded key instead of the modulus, which is incorrect.

To fix the issue, the modulus must be extracted from the PEM key. For this purpose, the PEM key can be loaded with a PEM parser, e.g. [lapo.it/asn1js](https://lapo.it/asn1js), and the modulus can be determined:

```
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
```

In XML format the modulus is expected Base64 encoded, which is feasible e.g. online with [cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex):

```
81dCnCKt0NVH7j5Oh2+SGgEU0aqi5u6sYXemouJWXOlZO3jqDsHYM1qfEjVvCOmeoMNFXYSXdNhflU7mjWP8jWUmkYIQ8o3FGqMzsMTNxr+bAp0cULWu9eYmycjJwWIxxB7vUwvpEUNicgW7v5nCwmF5HS33Hmn7yDzcfjfBs99K5xJEppHG0qc+q3YXxxPpwZNIRFn0Wtxt0Muh1U8avvWyw03uQ/wMBnzhwUC8T4G5NclLEWzOQExbQ4oDlZBv8BM/WxxuOyu0I8bDUDdutJOfREYRZBlazFHvRKNNQQD2qDfjRz484uFs7b5nykjaMB9k/EJAuHjJzGs9MMMWtQ==
```

Alternatively, an online converter can be used to convert the PEM key directly into the XML format, e.g. [superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter](https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter):

```xml
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>81dCnCKt0NVH7j5Oh2+SGgEU0aqi5u6sYXemouJWXOlZO3jqDsHYM1qfEjVvCOmeoMNFXYSXdNhflU7mjWP8jWUmkYIQ8o3FGqMzsMTNxr+bAp0cULWu9eYmycjJwWIxxB7vUwvpEUNicgW7v5nCwmF5HS33Hmn7yDzcfjfBs99K5xJEppHG0qc+q3YXxxPpwZNIRFn0Wtxt0Muh1U8avvWyw03uQ/wMBnzhwUC8T4G5NclLEWzOQExbQ4oDlZBv8BM/WxxuOyu0I8bDUDdutJOfREYRZBlazFHvRKNNQQD2qDfjRz484uFs7b5nykjaMB9k/EJAuHjJzGs9MMMWtQ==</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Both, of course, provide the same modulus.

Another possibility is that in the C# code the PEM key is imported *directly*. In .NET Core, as of version 3.0, the [`RSA.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=net-5.0) method is available to import a DER encoded key in X.509/SPKI format. The DER encoding results from the PEM encoded key by removing header, footer and line breaks and Base64 decoding the rest. In lower .NET Core versions or in .NET Framework the import of PEM keys is supported by BouncyCastle.

With the correct modulus, the C# code provides a correct ciphertext.

---

Note that the Python and JavaScript code use a different padding than the C# code. The Python and JavaScript code apply PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, while the C# code uses OAEP. For the C# code to also apply PKCS#1 v1.5, [`RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt?view=net-5.0#system-security-cryptography-rsacryptoserviceprovider-encrypt(system-byte-system-boolean)) must pass a `false` in the second parameter.